# How can I get the body of a message using JavaMail?

Tags: java, jsoup, jakarta-mail, message

Is there anyway to read in the body of a message using JavaMail? I'm able to read the body, but when I convert it to a string and print it, it's in HTML format. I just need the text. Obviously, I could use JSoup to parse it. But is there any other easier, quicker way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: So the body is HTML. It's still the body. That's the way it was sent. There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If stackoverflow would let me give a simple answer, it would be "no".

Answer (score 0):

you can put this method to remove html tag from string

```
//html = mail Content message
public static String removeHtmlTag(String html){
    return html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 4 type of body message of mail

1. TEXT/HTML / TEXT/PLAIN

2.MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE

3.MULTIPART/RELATED

4.MULTIPART/MIXED

if you have simple text message in body

use 1. type in TEXT/HTML OR TEXT/PLAIN

direct check message contentype

String contentType=message.getContentTyp();

if(contentType.equals("text/plain")){

Print Here......

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use IOUtils.toString(..) from Apache Commons.